# Are there particularly good inputs for quick sort and merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I had a test with these questions and my teacher told me I was wrong on everything. I tried to reason with him but he says I'm wrong.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with them?

1. **Are there particularly good inputs (that would produce low complexity) for
   Quicksort?** (inputs can be ordered, reverse ordered, random, etc., etc.)

   The lowest complexity that can be achieved through Quick Sort is the same as the average case which is `O(n log n)`. The best case is when the partitioning produces two sub-files of equal size every time.

   Example: Average Case & Best Case both = `C(n)` = `2C(n/2) + an`. When solved, this produces a complexity `C(n) = n lg n + an`, which is equivalent to `O(n log n)`.
2. **Are there particularly good inputs for Mergesort?**

   Because the complexity of Merge Sort is always `O(n log n)` and there are not any inputs that can beat this, there are not any particularly good inputs for Merge Sort.

   Example: `C(n) = 2C(n/2) + an` - when solved, this produces a complexity of `C(n) = n lg n + an`, which is equivalent to `O(n log n)`.

Comment: What answers does your teacher give?

Comment: best case quicksort `O(n)`, best case naive Mergesort `O(nlogn)`, best case native mergesort `O(n)`. Why argue over something which is documented?

Comment: @UmNyobe: Best case for classic QuickSort is `O(N log N)`. Claiming that `O(N)` is the best case for QuickSort is a rather ridiculous thing to do. Formally, one can prepend a QuickSort with a straighforward `O(N)` check, testing whether the array is already sorted. The overall algorithm will obviously remain `O(N log N)` and will still use QuickSort, but the already sorted input will be detected in `O(N)`.

Comment: Is this enough to claim that QuickSort's best case is `O(N)`? No. This is just a trick that has nothing to do with QuickSort itself. The same applies to all other tricks that claim to produce a QuickSort with `O(N)` best case.

Comment: @AndreyT 3way quicksort performs linear time on some inputs, but that's not the generic algorithm, at least not the one you learn in college. If they saw that version in class the TA is correct, otherwise not.

Comment: @AndreyT I think UmNyobe is probably referring to the three-way partition variant of quicksort, which would give linear time-complexity if all values in the array were equal.